# React jsfiddle setup not working with ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsfiddle, reactjs

I have tried to run React Dropdown from https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown/blob/master/index.js to the react jsfiddle set up https://jsfiddle.net/rajcse111/69z2wepo/13405/

I have pasted the code from github to jsfiddle set up for react, but it is not working.

Could anyone please show me example to run simple hello world on jsfiddle for react using ecmascript 6.

I tried simple example:

```
import React from 'react';

export class class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }

render(){
   <div>
   <input type="text" />
   </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

But this is also not working.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to precompile it with babeljs or something of that nature, since browsers don't support a lot of ES6 features yet, nor do they support JSX. Easiest way to do this is paste your code in http://babeljs.io/repl/, and copy the output into jsfiddle. You'll need to be sure to add a CDN link or something to include the react.js source as well.